# Group homomorphisms into groups with addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are there group homomorphisms other than logarithm into groups with addition? What I mean is, suppose

$h(x*y) = h(x) + h(y)$

are there other $h$ and $*$ than logarithm and multiplication that satisfy the above? Say, for real (or complex) numbers.

I'm a total newbie in group theory and homomorphisms — please excuse any mistakes. Any pointers into source material to start investigating these topics are much appreciated.

Comment: Which *symbol* we use for a group operation is essentially arbitrary. It is true that we tend to us $+$ only for abelian operations, but $\times$ is often abelian, as well. So there is really no such thing as "groups with addition."

Comment: $2(x+y) = 2(x) + 2(y)$, so replacing $h$ by $2$ and $*$ by $+$, you get another family of examples. I'm not sure what other possibilities for "*" on the real or complex numbers you would want to consider.

Comment: I'm really in over my head here, so I'm not even sure if it's relevant to consider any other possibilities for the group operation — is it? What I'm basically asking is if it's possible to have a transformation that turns some operations (and commonly, which) into additions, like logarithm does to multiplication?

Comment: I suppose the question should (could?) be "Let $(\mathbb{F}, \ast, +)$ be a field. What are the functions, if there are any, which map the group $(\mathbb{F}\setminus\{0\}, \ast)$ onto the group $(\mathbb{F}, +)$?"

Answer (score 4):

The use of $*$ vs. $+$ for a group operation is somewhat arbitrary and up to the author...except that $+$ is supposed to denote an *abelian* group operation, that is, one that commutes. So unless you are talking about a particular group (for instance, restrict the question to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as you suggest), then the question doesn't have a lot of meaning. In any case, note there is a trivial counter-example of the zero map, which is a homomorphism.

More to your question, I believe that $\log$ is completely characterized by being a non-zero homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R^{>0}},*)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, but I don't know a proof offhand. Perhaps someone can post one. In the complex numbers I believe you have trouble because of the multi-valuedness of $\log$.

Comment: I think you might need $\log$ to be a continuous homomorphism.

Comment: If $f : (\mathbb R_{>0}, *) \to (\mathbb R, +)$ is a homomorphism, then $x \mapsto f(e^x)$ is an additive map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (this is basically equivalent). This is known as "Cauchy's functional equation". In particular it's known there are non linear solutions. Under mild assumptions (for example continuity) then they are the only solutions, though.

Comment: I think you might need f to satisfy two more properties. 1- it's differentiable and 2- $log(a)=1$. As you know, logarithm in any basis would satisfy the homomorphism property and differentiability, so you may need to define its value at a point to get a unique function.